# Mysql fails to save UTF string in some cases

Tags: mysql

during spam fighting, I found some spam comments stored without any content...

After trying to isolate the problem, here is what I have found after saving similar comments to file along with the MySQL database...

This is (HEX because of unknown input encoding) what comment first few "chars"  look like:

```
D1EA E0F7 E0F2 FC20 EFEE EFF3 EBFF F0ED FBE5 20EF F0EE E3F0 E0EC ECFB
```

After executing `INSERT INTO test VALUES (0xD1EAE0F7E0F2FC20EFEEEFF3EBFFF0EDFBE520EFF0EEE3F0E0ECECFB21),(0x21D1EAE0F7E0F2FC20EFEEEFF3EBFFF0EDFBE520EFF0EEE3F0E0ECECFB), (0x21)` test mysql table (utf-8) contains 3 rows, first without any text, second and third with single character "!" as a text... (note that 21 hex code for "!" is also in the end of first entry, yet it is not saved). (latin1 encoding saved some useless text replacements for every byte, but this post is not about it)

Of course, D1EA (D=1101 0001 should be followed by one 10xxxxxx byte, not 1110xxxx) isn't valid UTF-8 character, but robust system like database server should be able to deal with it...

My guess is, Mysql (ver. 5.1.66-0+squeeze1) shouldn't choose when to save data and when not, even if it's not valid UTF-8 encoded character... Or at least, it should not claim query was successfull when it decides not to store the data!

Is it bug in mysql, or what?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Encoding is Windows-1251, and decodes to

```
Скачать популярные программы
//"Download popular software" google translated
```

You should reject non-UTF8 input in your code before doing anything with it.

```
if( !mb_check_encoding($input, "UTF-8") ) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
    die("Invalid encoding");
}
```

FTR, your queries are hex literals, not misencoded text.

Comment: thanks for that, I will use this contition to prevent such junk comments... Problem with mysql not saving data claiming it was successfully saved, however, persists and this is not universal solution

Comment: you have to modify every system to check request encoding. But every system already checks result of mysql query, so it should be mysql telling, "no, this data haven't been saved" insted of "OK, go on"...